# I am unable to execute validation in Backbone.js.

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Whenever I set the age attribute to negative value it doesn't return false.
I have also tried executing this code in the console and still nothing happens

```
<script>
        var Human = Backbone.Model.extend({
      // If you return a string from the validate function,
      // Backbone will throw an error
      defaults: {
        name: 'Guest user',
        age: 23,
        occupation: 'worker'
      },
      validate: function( attributes ){
        if( attributes.age < 0){
            return "Age must me positive";
        }
        if( !attributes.name ){
            return 'Every person must have a name';
        }

      },
     work: function(){
      return this.get('name') + ' is working';
       }
     });



      var human = new Human;

      human.set("age", -10);  

    human.on('error', function(model, error){
        console.log(error);
      });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

1. The event for validation is `invalid`, `error` is for ajax requests.
2. Validation on set doesn't happen by default, you need to pass `{ validate: true }` as an option.
3. You are listening to the event AFTER setting, so it won't get called for that set.

i.e:

```
human.on('invalid', function(model, error) {
  console.log(error);
});

human.set("age", -10, { validate: true });
```